# Web scraping using regex

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, typeerror

I'm running into a wall why this code does not work, even thought it's the same code as on an online tutorial [Python Web Scraping Tutorial 5 (Network Requests)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FoSwMZ4uJg&t=6m22s). I tried running the code also via online Python interpreter.

```
import urllib
import re

htmltext = urllib.urlopen("https://www.google.com/finance?q=AAPL")

regex = '<span id="ref_[^.]*_l">(.+?)</span>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
results = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
results
```

I get:

```
re.pyc in findall(pattern, string, flags)
175 
176     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 177     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
178 
179 if sys.hexversion >= 0x02020000:

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Expected result(s):

```
112.71
```

Help appreciated. I tried using "read()" on the url but that didn't work. According to documentation even empty results should be included. Thanks

Comment: There is error in your regex pattern, correct pattern would be `<span id="ref_[^.]*_l">(.+?)<\/span>`

Comment: If the tutorial you're using suggests using regular expressions to scrape the web, find a different one; HTML parsers exist for a reason.

Comment: @ZdaR well no... `/` doesn't require escaping in regular expressions...

Comment: @ZdaR Thanks, but it doesn't seem to get the code going. Same error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I def could do that. Any idea what could be wrong here ? thanks!

Comment: @Smolo yeah... definitely listen to Jon - bad tutorials won't help you learning here and this one definitely isn't... anyway... try `htmltext.read().decode('utf8')` and see if that does it...

Comment: Any tutorial that tells you to  parse html with a regex should be avoided. Beautifulsoup can do this reliably  in a single line `BeautifulSoup(htmltext).select("span[id^=ref_]")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/156755

Comment: as mentioned above a few times - dont use regex to parse html

Comment: Sure, don't use regex to do that. But read/listen the video tutorial until the end ! After this ugly fetching the guy explains a quite better practice by using google API detected from network panel from google dev tools

Comment: @GillesQuenot I think people here offering their free time and experience aren't really going to listen to a youtube video attempting: "You really don't want to do this, but now we've wasted your time watching this and causing you having to ask a question to clarify things, now let's show you a correct way"?

Comment: Thanks for the help though !

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the tutorial until the end :) :

```
% python2                                                                                                     
>>> import urllib
>>> data = urllib.urlopen('https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=AAPL&x=NASD&i=10&p=25m&f=c&auto=1').read()
>>> print data.split()[-1]
112.71
```

Never use regex to web scrape

I make improvement to fetch last array element simpler

Comment: Thanks Gilles, but that's a different URL that you're opening. I did follow tutorial until the end, but I still don't understand why the same piece of code works differently for different people/environments. I appreciate tho!

Comment: This is the URL used at the end of the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not actually read the HTML from the request.

```
htmltext = urllib.urlopen("https://www.google.com/finance?q=AAPL").read()
```

Comment: Umm... the OP has said *I tried using "read()" on the url but that didn't work*...

Comment: Well they should show that code; this works for me. And this is definitely Python 2, since `urllib.urlopen` doesn't exist in Python 3.

Comment: Right, so I'm not getting any error, but instead just an empty result ... which I shouldn't because the pattern occurs few times within the page.

Comment: @Smolo,  it returns `['112.71']` and there is one occurrence that matches the pattern not multiple. If you get nothing you are probably not getting the same source back for various reasons.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm executing the code via Python shell 2.7.6, as well as via Python run in the cloud (if there are to be any differences in output between the two). Here's a link to the code http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSkplYjVvbklUUzQ How can I dig deeper into why we're getting different results ? Thanks!